# How to retrieve the url inAppBrowser currently in

Tags: javascript, url, cordova, inappbrowser

I am trying to do oAuth with Google using InAppBrowser for Cordova and I need to retrieve the current url in order to store the access token. I was wondering if there is a certain command to retrieve the current URL that the user is at.
My code :

```
window.open( authUri, { showLocationBar : false } );

window.open( authUri, { showLocationBar : false } ).addEventListener( 'loadstart', function() {
    if ( event.url.indexOf( "code=" ) != -1 )
    {
        alert( "hey" );
        var lel = URL;
    }
});

window.open( lel, { showLocationBar : false } ).addEventListener( 'loadstart', $this.onAuthUrlChange );
window.open( lel, { showLocationBar : false } ).addEventListener( 'loadstop', $this.onAuthClose );
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved using something like this

```
this.document.location.href
```